# How to use SLIME as a proxy between Common Lisp program and Emacs Lisp?

Tags: slime, common-lisp

I'm looking into doing the following: I have a program written in Common Lisp, which I want to be able to communicate with Emacs. The program deals with natural language parsing, so the things I'd need to access in Emacs would be the contents of the buffer and some minimal preliminary parsing required to create messages to send to the Common Lisp program. The Common Lisp program will then process the messages and reply to the Emacs Lisp program, so that it will display the results.

I understand that SLIME would be a good tool to use to achieve this, mainly because it already does most of it, but looking into documentation I find that it's a "user documentation" kind, not a "developer documentation". Essentially, I would like to know what is the minimum that I could use on the Emacs Lisp side to get the communication going (I certainly don't need the introspection, or REPL in this case, all I need is to send messages to and from my program running in SWANK).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the CL side the function you are looking for is `swank::eval-in-emacs` to which you pass a the code you want to evaluate in emacs. You can see an example [here](https://github.com/PuercoPop/cl-datastructures/blob/master/src/binary-tree.lisp#L172), to make emacs run the graphivz command and open the resulting png in a buffer. From the emacs side the function you are looking for is slime-eval (found in slime.el)

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while to get back to it.